# What is default error threshold Tensorflow?

Tags: error, tensorflow

My homework states that I am asked "to report the default error threshold used in the TensorFlow default configuration for convergence. Usually it is
documented for MNIST and CIFAR-10".

What's that? I am a beginner of BigData and this is my first project using Tensorflow